# Create column in R data frame with second highest value in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

Sorry if I am asking a trivial question, but the fact is I have spent a few hours reading answers in this data base and could not find what I am looking for.

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
df=data.frame(v1=c(24,15, 0, 7,36,10), c1=c(22,15,0,0,28,11), v2=c(0,10,0,19,0,0), c2=c(0,7,0,22,0,0), v3=c(54,22,28,55,62,38), c3=c(44,23,22,66,71,44))
```

(The original, of course, has many more rows and columns)

I would like to create two columns with the maximum and the second highest values of all the "v" columns.

For the maximum, this works:

```
df$max.v=mapply(FUN=max, df$v1, df$v2, df$v3, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But I cannot find a way to do it for the second highest value. 
It probably needs some kind of function, but I could not find how to do it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10296866/946850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the accepted answer in the question linked by @krlmlr is dubious, because `apply` can break data frames. It doesn't matter so much in this case, because all the columns must be numeric for the question to make sense, but I prefer to err on the safe side.

Instead, use `do.call` with `mapply`, and persuade it to treat a df as a list:

```
do.call(mapply, c(function(...) sort(c(...), dec=TRUE)[1:2],
        df[grepl("v", names(df))]))
```

Comment: I think the OP only wanted the "v" columns to be considered. So the final argument would be better as `df[grepl("v",names(df))]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am impressed, and humbly aware of how little I know about R yet.

Comment: Since I do not know how to create two columns in one go I have adapted your code, copying everything and substituting the [1:2] for [1] in the first column and [2] for the other. It works great.