# Finding the 2nd Max value in R data table

Tags: r, max

I have a data table that has a int column that is counting the iteration of a test that I've preformed. So the first time I preformed the test, `Table$Column == 1` and the second time `Table$Column == 2` and so on and so forth.

However, there are times when a test breaks or I don't want to use the results from a particular test run. I have code that compares the current run vs. the previous run that looks like this.

```
vLatest<-max(Table$Column)
vPrevious<-max(Table$Column)-1
```

But since I sometimes omit results, it breaks vPrevious. How could I replace the "-1" with a function that finds the "2nd" max value?

Comment: It would be better if you provided a reproducible example. Also the code `max(Table$Column)-1` would just find the maximum value then subtract 1, not the 2nd max.

Comment: That's the point.... I said that -1 doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the column number and value the of second highest value in a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296866/finding-the-column-number-and-value-the-of-second-highest-value-in-a-row)

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
vPrevious <- sort(Table$Column, decreasing=T)[2]
```

We first sort in descending order and then pick the second element.

Comment: This is actually only partially correct. This wasn't in the original question but there are duplicate entries (multiple entries per test run). Is there a way to sort through the distinct numbers?

Comment: And this doesn't work if you have many columns