# How to find Customers with Highest and second Highest sales?

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

I need to find out Customer Names, who made highest and second highest purchase.

Sample Data

```
Name   Sales
pavan  400
kumar  200
mahesh 750
rajesh 550
vasu   900
```

There should be two queries one for highest and one for second highest.
I want only names not row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296866/finding-the-column-number-and-value-the-of-second-highest-value-in-a-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

**R Base Solution**

Make sure the Name is `Character` type

**For Max**

```
df[which.max(df$Sales),]$Name
#[1] "vasu"
```

**For Min**

```
df[which.min(df$Sales),]$Name
#[1] "kumar"
```

It is to note that `which` returns the index. So in the above case, `which.max` returns the index of maximum Sale Value and vice versa. Hence I am sending the index in subsetting enclosure of R.

**Second Highest**

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% arrange(desc(Sales))
df$Name[2]
#mahesh
```

You can keep changing the index to get the 3rd and 4th.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How to find second highest?

Comment: @PavanKumar I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried second Highest query, it is retrieving second row from table, but i want second highest by their Sales value.

Comment: @PavanKumar Please check now! I made an edit. make sure Sales is `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

your should first search for your problems in posts.

second, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   summarise_at(c('Name', "Sales"), max, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
   select(Name)
```

output is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Name 
  <chr>
1 vasu
```

you can replace the function `max` with `min` to receive your desired output. or quote `select(Name)` to receive bot values.

Comment: Thanks it's working for highest, How to find out customer with second highest value?